# Get Azure Active Directory Group Principal Id

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-graph, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to get Active Directory group Principal Id through Graph API or SharePoint Online REST API.

I want to use that principal id in SharePoint workflow to add permission to the list item